# NPM, downloads dependencies from wrong URL address

Tags: node.js, npm

After working with some project, my npm started to download dependencies from wrong address globally:

```
npm install -g bower

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://172.168.1.1/bower failed, reason: 
    connect ETIMEDOUT 172.168.1.1
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Is there some method to reset download address to default one?

I'm using Windows version of NodeJS

Comment: Check `registry` config setting: `npm config get registry`. It must be https://registry.npmjs.org

Comment: @alexmac Yes it has this address. How to drop it?

Comment: _this address_ means 172.168.1.1? If so use this command: `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: @alexmac That worked. Thank you. Can you write this as an answer with verbose description so I could accept it? This could help to other users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like your `registry` npm config option points to the wrong location. It must be https://registry.npmjs.org, check it with the following command:

```
npm config get registry
```

If your registry is different, use this command to set it correctly:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: npm config get registry - this one shows repository I expect to see and still npm install uses different repo..